# Controlling A1-16 motors using myRIO and LabVIEW

Tags: uart, labview

I would like to use the LabVIEW 2018 coding software along with myRIO-1900 to control my A1-16 servo motor. However, the A1-16 does not support Linux, and myRIO-1900 is partially based on Linux. Therefore, I am currently unsure how to use LabVIEW to control this servo motor. The servo motor uses UART communication protocol for operation. My current need is for someone to assist me in accomplishing this task.

I am currently attempting to use UART communication, connecting the input and output terminals to exchange information, but I don't know how to control this protocol on the servo motor.

Comment: You need to find documentation for the servo motor's command protocol, then write LabVIEW code to send and receive the appropriate serial commands. If you do that and still have a problem (and if you are sure that the hardware is correctly connected) then ask again, showing your LabVIEW code and describing what the problem is, and people will be able to try and help you.